# How to add new value on keyup to div every n digit with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to auto list numbers every time the user types in 3 digits. The input numbers should appear in the `div` automatically.

```js
$("#lister").on("keyup", function() {
  var mxlen = $(this).data("mxlen");
  var input = $(this).val();
  if (input.length == mxlen) { //if input==3
    $('#num_list').append('<li>' + input + '</li>');
    $(this).html(''); //clear input after appended
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num_list"></div>
<input type="number" id="lister" data-mxlen="3" />
```

The problem with my code is that it repeats the same numbers and does not clear the input after appending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost there, you just need to use `val('')` to reset the value.

Also note that you can make the logic more robust by using `slice(0, mxlen)` to restrict the value to 3 characters when typing quickly, and also change the check from `==` to `>=` for the same reason.

```js
$("#lister").on("input", function() {
  let $el = $(this);
  var mxlen = $el.data("mxlen");
  var input = $el.val();
  
  if (input.length >= mxlen) {
    $('#num_list').append('<li>' + input.slice(0, mxlen) + '</li>');
    $el.val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num_list"></div>
<input type="number" id="lister" data-mxlen="3" />
```

One last thing to note is that characters such as `-` or `e` are valid for entry in a `type="number"` input field, however they are not valid for the value *returned* from the field. As such the `length` check will get inconsistent output when these characters are used.

Depending on your use case you may be better off with a standard `type="text"` check and manually restricting the input to numerical values.